# Output-redirection should recreate the destination-file

Tags: linux, bash

I can redirect the output of a process to a file

```
./prog > a.txt
```

But if I delete a.txt and do not restart prog, then no more output will get into a.txt. The same is the case if I use the append-redirect >>.

Is there a way to make my redirection recreate the file when it is deleted during the runtime of prog?

Redirection is part of the OS I think and not of prog. So maybe there are some tools or settings.

Thanks!

Comment: The inode will be different for the newly created file. So you can't expect the process to write using the same file descriptor to a different inode. The inode table will still map to the descriptor of the deleted file. So what you expect can't be done without a program restart

Comment: I see the problem. But maybe there are some tools to handle that. Therefore the question.

Comment: You could use `logrotate` to automatically move the file to different location on certain conditions (timely/storage basis).

Comment: @Inian even if you move the file using `logrotate`, the application keeps writing to it until it exits. `logrotate` can restart the application or can send it a signal to let it know about the change; but a signal doesn't help here because the application doesn't manage itself the writing to the file.

Comment: @axiac: Yes I probably meant, configure `logrotate` to move the files on certain conditions and restart the application. Agree it can't be done on-the-fly without restart

Answer (score 3):

At the OS level, a file is made up of many components:

- the content, stored somewhere on the storage device;
- an i-node that keeps all file information except the name;
- the name, listed in a directory (also stored on the storage device);
- when the file is open, each application that opens it handle memory buffers that keep some of the file content.

All these are linked and the OS keeps their booking.

If you delete the file while it is open by another application (the redirect operator `>` keeps it open until `./prog` completes), only the name is removed from the directory. The other pieces of the puzzle are still there and they keep working until the last application that keeps the file open closes it. This is when the file content is discarded on the storage medium.

If you delete the file, while `./prog` keeps running and producing output the file grows and uses space on the storage medium but it cannot be open again because there is no way to access it. Only the programs that have it already open when it was deleted can still access the file until they close it.

Even if you re-create the file, it is a different file that happens to have the same name as the deleted one. `./prog` is not affected, its output goes to the old, deleted file.

When its output is redirected, apart from restarting `./prog`, there is no way to persuade it to store its output in a different file when `a.txt` is deleted.

There are several ways to make this happen if `./prog` writes itself into `a.txt` (they all require changing the code of `./prog`).

Comment: I will not change prog because I see redirection as a task for the OS. But  maybe it is time to create such a tool that can handle new files as well as timestamps in front of every entry.

Comment: `logrotate` is able to handle the file but since your program doesn't control the file all that `logrotate` can do is to restart your program after it moves the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gdb` to redirect the output of program to file when original file is deleted.

Refer to this [post](http://dnaeon.github.io/remove-file-handles-with-gdb/).

For later references, I give the only excerpt from the post:

1. Find the files that are opened by the process using `/proc/<pid>/fd`.
2. Attach the PID of program to `gdb`.
3. Close the file descriptor of the deleted file through `gdb` session.
4. Redirect the program output to another file using `gdb` calls.

**Examples**

Suppose that PID of program is 19080 and file descriptor of deleted file is 2.

```
gdb attach 19080

ls -l /proc/19080/fd

gdb> p close(2) 
$1 = 0
gdb> p fopen("/tmp/file", "w")
$2 = 20746416
(gdb) p fileno($2)
$3 = 7
gdb> quit
```

**N.B.:** If data of the deleted file is required, recover the deleted text file before closing the file handle:
`cp -pv /proc/19080/fd/2 recovered_file.txt`